# Creating array of threads on Windows

Tags: c, windows, multithreading

I'm trying to create an array of threads. In Linux, I did it this like:

```
pthread_t thr[MAXCONNECTIONS];
```

On Windows, I don't find any replacement for this. Is there anyway to create an array or something that replaces this?

Comment: why not just use pthreads on windows too. there seems to be a port.

Comment: Ow didn't know about that. I thought you must include process and then use beginthread and endthread...

Comment: @Tom: pthreads on Windows are available now? In a library? or does Windows support them?

Comment: http://sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
HANDLE threads[ThreadCount];

for (int i=0; i < ThreadCount; ++i)
{
   threads[i] = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex( NULL, 0, &ThreadFunc, NULL, 0, &threadID );
}
```

I've left out some stuff but you get the jist. You have an array of HANDLE's instead of physical threads. You can then pass a HANDLE to various functions to do things on the thread.

```
WaitForSingleObject(threads[2], INFINITE );
```

Answer (score 0):

suppose you want to create 10 threads

include this:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <process.h>
```

thread function look like this:

```
DWORD WINAPI thread_1(LPVOID lpParam){ /* do something */; return 0; }
```

array and thread creation:

```
HANDLE thr[10];
thr[0] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, thread_1, NULL, NULL, NULL);
... etc for 1..9
WaitForMultipleObjects(10, thr, TRUE, INFINITE);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the possibility to use `c++`, a more portable solution would be to use an array of [Boost threads](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/thread.html) (link to [Boost](http://www.boost.org/)). This will work with the same code on both Linux and Windows.

You could also use an array of `c++11` `std::thread`'s, which is also portable. Im not sure, but I understand that std::thread isnt complete yet for Windows, so you would probably be better off with Boost.